# How to insert .erb into a data-target parameter | Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I have a bootstrap(3.3) collapse used to reply to individual comments in my rails app.
The problem with collapse is the `data-target` and the `aria-controls` need to be unique for every comment. This is the case due to every comment being left holds the static value set to the first comment (`data-target="#collapse1"`)

I've tried to use some `ERB` like the following to insert a unique value in place of "1" so it can be a unique collapse for each comment.

This unfortunately didn't work: `data-target="<%= '#collapse#{@comment.id}' %>"`

Nor did my doubtful attempt of: `data-target=<%= "#collapse#{@comment.id}" %>` work.

I don't know if I'm just missing something completely obvious about `ERB` or if this really just isn't practical/possible with rails.

If this is much more suitable for Javascript or Jquery, please let me know. (and help me out if you can!)

Thanks in advance for sharing this awful experience with me.

**EDIT:**
This is the following code I am trying to manipulate:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success align-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Reply</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse1">
  <%= simple_form_for([comment, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.input :body, :as => :text, input_html: { maxlength: 300 }, label: false, placeholder: "What are your thoughts?", class: "form-control", wrapper_html: { id: 'contactTextarea' } %>
    <%= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "Name (required)", class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.input :email, label: false, placeholder: "Email Address (required) - This is not displayed with the comment", class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.submit "Reply", class: "btn btn-success" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

---

**PLAIN HTML EDIT:**

```
<div class="wellington top-drop">
  <h3 class="title-top align-left">Name</h3>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <p class="nobot align-left">Good stuff!</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success align-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse11" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapse11">Reply</button>
  <div class="collapse" id="#collapse11">
    <form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_comment" id="new_comment" action="/comments/11/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="[token]">

      <div id="contactTextarea" class="form-group text required comment_body"><textarea class="form-control text required" maxlength="300" placeholder="What are your thoughts?" name="comment[body]" id="comment_body"></textarea></div>
      <div class="form-group string required comment_name"><input class="form-control string required" placeholder="Name (required)" type="text" name="comment[name]" id="comment_name"></div>
      <div class="form-group email required comment_email"><input class="form-control string email required" placeholder="Email Address (required) - This is not displayed with the comment" type="email" name="comment[email]" id="comment_email"></div>
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-success" data-disable-with="Reply">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

**FINAL EDIT (THE WORKING CODE):**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success align-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="<%= "#collapse#{comment.id}" %>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="<%= "collapse#{comment.id}" %>">Reply</button>
<div class="collapse" id="<%= "collapse#{comment.id}" %>">
  <[reply form]>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try  `data-target='<%= "#collapse#{@comment.id}" %>'` ?

Comment: @RaviMariya I just tried it but unfortunately it raised this error `undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Because you're @comment is nil

Comment: Where do you define `@comment`, you sure isn't `comment`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma You're right, I think it's supposed to be `comment` I made a foolish mistake, it is all insde a partial `<%= render(partial: 'comments/comment', collection: @post.comments) %>` I changed it all over to `"<%= "#collapse#{comment.id}" %>"` but it still leaves the "Reply" buttons useless.

Comment: In plain HTML, what's rendering now?

Comment: @SebastianPalma I've updated my question with plain HTML.

Comment: You're getting `#collapse11`, what should it be?

Comment: @Jake you are now getting to far, you're question is about to insert data-attributes parameter. It is not working because it can be possibly caused by your JS. Did you check what everything not just your HTML thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-target="<%= '#collapse#{@comment.id}' %>"` won't raise an error because the expression within the ERB tags is rendered just as a "plain" string, as per the single quotes.

In an ERB template you can add any data attributes like any other, `data-target="<%= "#collapse#{@comment.id}" %>"` should work, if you're sure @comment isn't nil and can return its id.

Comment: The first way of doing this you provided doesn't raise any errors but it doesn't let any of the buttons toggle any collapse. Please note; I am including this into my collapse `id` field as well.

Comment: It won't raise any error because is a "whole-plain" string, as isn't with double quotes, it won't be interpolated, you're going to see the same `'#collapse#{@comment.id}'`. Try second way. Inspect the element, see (copy/paste here) what you get.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, you're right, the fault was in my copy/paste job from each `aria-controls=" "` and `div id=" "`

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
data: { target: "#collapse<%=@comment.id%>" }
```

As with the comment, asking how to properly format or I think he want to add another `data-attribubtes`, you can add it before or after the attributes, like this:

```
data: { target: "#collapse<%=@comment.id%>", toggle: "value-here" }
```

or

```
data: { toggle: "value-here", target: "#collapse<%=@comment.id%>" }
```

Here is the above code you posted:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success align-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Reply</button>
```

And I think you want it to be like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success align-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<%=@comment.id %>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse<%=@comment.id%>">Reply</button>
```

And if you want it do do in Rails erb format, it can be like this:

```
<%= button_tag "Name of your Button", class: "btn btn-xs btn-success align-right", data: {toggle: "collapse", target: "#collapse<%=@comment.id %>", expanded: "false"}, "aria-controls": "collapse<%=@comment.id%>" %>
```

Comment: How would I properly format this with multiple `data` attributes in a row? Such as: `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1"`

Comment: @Jake you can add it after or before target. I'll update my answer it for you. But, did I answer your question correctly?

Comment: This is what I'm after, but when introducing `aria:` in the same fashion after it, it wouldn't work. I think I'm running into problems with putting the same value in the separate `div`'s `id` field. I will update my question with appropriate code.

Comment: @Jake You can't add aria-expanded inside `data: {}`, what you can do is wrap it with qoutes. `"aria-expanded": "false"`

Comment: @Jake, answer was updated. I hope you got the right answer.

Comment: This unfortunately fails. I think it has to do with the collapse `div`'s `id=" "` having issues with the ERB.

Comment: Did you check your JS? Collapsing is not HTML job.

Comment: I'm not sure how the JS could be an issue since the collapse worked before when it was just `collapse1` etc. as static values. Only now it raises problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
data-target='<%= "#collapse#{@comment.id}" %>'
```

Or more simple way

```
data-target="#collapse#{@comment.id}"
```